# Problem doing Multiple Join for Index View Controller

Tags: c#

I want to use a join in my index controller so that my index view has the user friendly data from the normalized tables.

I am struggling to do this with MVC5, as it is new to me.  Below is my code for my index controller.  It is not working, and I know there is something I am missing or have wrong - but I don't know what.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ICS20web.Models;
using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

namespace ICS20web.Controllers
{
    public class InternalOrdersController : Controller
    {
          private ICS_Internal_Transactions db = new ICS_Internal_Transactions();

    // GET: InternalOrders
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var q = from tr in db.ICS_Transactions

                join un in db.ICS_Units 
                on tr.DeliveryUnitID equals un.DeliveryUnitID


                 join kt in db.ICS_Contacts 
                 on tr.Contact equals kt.LoginID

                 join sp in db.ICS_Supplies on tr.SuppliesID equals sp.Supplies_ID

                 select new { sp.ItemDescription, tr.OriginalDate, tr.TransType, tr.LastUpdatedBy , kt.ContactName, tr.OpenClosed, tr.CurrentStatus, tr.CurrentStatusDate, tr.RequsitionNumber, tr.PONumber, tr.DeliveryMonth, tr.DeliveryYear, tr.UnitsOrdered, tr.Emergency, tr.Comments, un.DeliveryUnit, un.PhoneNumber, un.Street, un.City, un.State, un.ZipCode, un.Building, un.Room};



        return View(q.ToList());


     //   return View(db.ICS_Transactions.ToList());
    }
```

Here is the actual error that is kicking ou

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType5`23[System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ICS20web.Models.ICS_Transactions]'.

Comment: whats exactly not working? are you getting any runtime errors or compilation errors?

Comment: @Stormhashe - I updated my question with the (runtime) error, and more of the controller code too.

Comment: Show  your view file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model in your view is expecting a type of `IEnumerable<ICS20web.Models.ICS_Transactions>` or something along those lines, but you are passing an anonymous object to your view.

You need to create a ViewModel class and then change the model on your view to that class.

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public string ItemDescription {get; set;}
    public DateTime OriginalDate {get; set;}
    /* ... additional properties ...*/
}
```

Then change your query:

```
var q = from tr in db.ICS_Transactions
        join un in db.ICS_Units on tr.DeliveryUnitID equals un.DeliveryUnitID
        /* ... */
        select new IndeViewModel{ 
                  ItemDescrition = sp.ItemDescription, 
                  OriginalDate = tr.OriginalDate, 
                  /* ... */
        };
```

And finally in your Index.cshtml (or whatever your view is called) changed the model declaration to

```
 @model YournameSpace.IndexViewModel
```

Comment: Thanks @Marco.  This was exactly what I needed. It's straightforward.  I understand now, why it was not working.  Your solution solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting a new object type (anonymous object) which is different from the one in ur view

this part  `select new { sp.ItemDescription, tr.OriginalDate, tr.TransType, tr.LastUpdatedBy , kt.ContactName, tr.OpenClosed, tr.CurrentStatus, tr.CurrentStatusDate, tr.RequsitionNumber, tr.PONumber, tr.DeliveryMonth, tr.DeliveryYear, tr.UnitsOrdered, tr.Emergency, tr.Comments, un.DeliveryUnit, un.PhoneNumber, un.Street, un.City, un.State, un.ZipCode, un.Building, un.Room};`